# Communicate multiple times with a process without breaking the pipe?

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

It's not the first time I'm having this problem, and it's really bugging me.
Whenever I open a pipe using the Python `subprocess` module, I can only `communicate` with it once, as the documentation specifies: `Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached`

```
proc = sub.Popen("psql -h darwin -d main_db".split(),stdin=sub.PIPE,stdout=sub.PIPE)
print proc.communicate("select a,b,result from experiment_1412;\n")[0]
print proc.communicate("select theta,zeta,result from experiment_2099\n")[0]
```

The problem here is that the second time, Python isn't happy. Indeed, he decided to close the file after the first communicate:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "a.py", line 30, in <module>
    print proc.communicate("select theta,zeta,result from experiment_2099\n")[0]
File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 667, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 1124, in _communicate
     self.stdin.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Are multiple communications allowed?

Comment: for psql, there are many existing Python wrappers: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you misunderstand communicate...

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

communicate sends a string to the other process and then waits on it to finish... (Like you said waits for the EOF listening to the stdout & stderror)

What you should do instead is:

```
proc.stdin.write('message')

# ...figure out how long or why you need to wait...

proc.stdin.write('message2')
```

(and if you need to get the stdout or stderr you'd use proc.stdout or proc.stderr)

Comment: I realized you might want to look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-stream-in-python (It's a very similar problem)

Comment: Yes indeed, I needed non-blocking reads, because the write might always depend on what was read.

Comment: Warning from the [`subprocess` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr):

> Warning: Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Answer (score 6):

I've had this problem before, and as far as I could ever figure, you couldn't do this with `subprocess` (which, I agree, is very counterintuitive if true).  I ended up using `pexpect` (obtainable from PyPI).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
proc.stdin.write('input')    
if proc.stdout.closed:
    print(proc.stdout)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this simply with single call of `communicate()`:

```
query1 = 'select a,b,result from experiment_1412;'
query1 = 'select theta,zeta,result from experiment_2099;'
concat_query = "{}\n{}".format(query1, query2)
print(proc.communicate(input=concat_query.encode('utf-8'))[0])
```

The key-point here is that you only write once to `stdin`, and `\n` serve as EOL. 
your psql subprocess reads from `stdin` until `\n`, then after it finishes the first query, it goes to `stdin` again, by which time only the second query string is left in the buffer.

Comment: This buffers the entire input in memory, making the solution less than ideal for situations where streaming I/O is desired.