# Send and receive data multiple times to subprocess (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess

## Issue

I am communicating with a terminal application (xfoil) and I want to isolate the stdout corresponding to each stdin.
This question is also more general as I wish to know why I can't open an application with subprocess, and then use successively its stdin and stdout (or rather how could I do it).

## What I can do now

As of now, I can send instructions to Xfoil using `process.communicate` which retrieves the entire stdout.

```py
import subprocess
xfoil = subprocess.Popen('path_to_xfoil.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, \
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
[output, _] = xfoil.communicate(input=instructions)
```

## What I want to achieve

Instead of having to deal with the entire stdout, I wish to isolate each set of instructions (stdin) and results (stdout).
Something in the lines of:

```py
output1 = process.communicate(input=instructions1)
output2 = process.communicate(input=instructions2)
output3 = process.communicate(input=instructions3)
...
```

I need the process to stay open (which is not the case with communicate).

## What I have attempted

[Communicate multiple times with a process without breaking the pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3066718/11225613) is probably the way to go, however it does not explain clearly how to read the output, and the following piece of code simply freezes, probably because I have no idea when read should stop.

```py
xfoil.stdin.write(instructions1)
xfoil.stdout.read()  # never passes this line
xfoil.stdin.write(instructions2)
xfoil.stdout.read()
```

[Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/11225613) seemed a good path as well, however it only takes care of output.

Or perhaps I need to use the `os` module as in [ipc - communicate multiple times with a subprocess in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41147557/11225613) ?

Thank you for your help

PS: I read a tiny bit about `fcntl` but I need the code to work on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate?

Comment: Attempted that as well, it freezes when I intend to read xfoil.stdout (with ``for line in xfoil.stdout: print(line, end='')``).