# Using ffmpeg to create video from images - Python

Tags: python, image, video, ffmpeg, python-imaging-library

I'm using FFMPEG in python ([using this tutorial](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/)) and my main goal is to take a screenshot and append it into an existing mp4 video(append it using the encoder, not raw appending).

That's the code I'm using right now, this script only writes a video of one frame(the first screenshot) and doesn't do anything with all the other screenshots.

```
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-codec', 'rawvideo',
    '-s', '1920x1080', # size of one frame
    '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
    '-r', '24', # frames per second
    '-i', '-', # The input comes from a pipe
    '-an', # Tells FFMPEG not to expect any audio
    '-vcodec', 'mpeg4',
    'my_output_videofile.mp4' ]

for x in range(30):
    pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdin = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE)
    im = np.array(ImageGrab.grab()).tostring()
    pipe.communicate(input = im)
    pipe.stdin.close()
    if pipe.stderr is not None:
        pipe.stderr.close()
    pipe.wait()
```

Edit:
Apparently using Popen.communicate breaks the pipe (Thanks to Peter Wood !).

After fixing the pipe breaking scenario I have encountered another problem, after writing ~ 235 frames to the video the program crashes.

The new edited script:

```
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
    '-y',
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-codec', 'rawvideo',
    '-s', '1920x1080', # size of one frame
    '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
    '-r', '24', # frames per second
    '-i', '-', # The input comes from a pipe
    '-an', # Tells FFMPEG not to expect any audio
    '-vcodec', 'mpeg4',
    'my_output_videofile.mp4' ]

pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdin = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE)

for x in range(300):
    print x

    im = np.array(ImageGrab.grab()).tostring()
    pipe.stdin.write(im)
    pipe.stdin.flush()
```

Comment: Each loop you call the command again. Will that overwrite the output file? Maybe create the pipe outside the loop.

Comment: @PeterWood I've been trying that method of creating the pipe outside the loop and writing in every iteration but after writing the first frame the pipe automatically closes...

Comment: See [Communicate multiple times with a process without breaking the pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065060/communicate-multiple-times-with-a-process-without-breaking-the-pipe)

Comment: @PeterWood That actually fixed the problem !
But another problem I'm encountering right now is when I'm trying to write ~235 frames my script freezes, I'll edit the original post with the new script.

Comment: You should create a new question, and try to come up with a minimal example. See how to create a [mcve]. It's possible, as you don't read from `stdout` (or `stderr`) it's blocking. See [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)