# How do I send a string from python to the Linux terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, text-to-speech, raspberry-pi4

I have a string named `TextInput` that contains a simple input message from the user and I am trying to experiment with getting it to be read aloud with the `mimic3` tts engine. I need it to play without me having to type it into the terminal myself. Here is what I've got:

```
import os
TextInput = input("Text:  ")
os.system('mimic3 --interactive')
```

I need something that will take TextInput, type it in the terminal, and then run it

I am running this on a raspberry pi 4b 8gb with Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit installed

I have tried using the `pyautogui` module, but it didn't run the terminal afterwards

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` will block until the command finishes ... try `subprocess` instead

```py
proc=subprocess.Popen('mimic3 --interactive',stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(5) # give it a bit to start up
proc.stdin.write("hello\n")
```

I would expect to work... without trying it...

Comment: when I tried that I got this error:                                                                                             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/the-doctor/Python/test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    proc=subprocess.Popen('mimic3 --interactive',stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderror=subprocess.PIPE)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stderror'

Comment: @DrDark, maybe try `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` instead of `stderror=subprocess.PIPE`.

Comment: thanks for the correction :) fixed now

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work by doing:

```
import time
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['mimic3', '--interactive'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
proc.stdin.write('systems online\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(10)

while True:
    text = input("text: ")
    proc.stdin.write(text + '\n')
    proc.stdin.flush()
```

I found the what I needed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3066718/20184203)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).